# Ideas for how to select an item from a dropdown dynamically using UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Ok, so the project I'm working on involves a webpage, on this webpage you can add rows of data into different sections. (say car manufacturer, car model etc) Anyways the problem I have is that the data in the drop-down could be different every time. Specifically there's a drop-down and I want to select one of the items from the list. I've added the drop-down icon but I need to be able to select an item regardless of what it's called. I have been able to do it if I give the absolute xpath, but it's very messy (and super long) and the team doesn't want to use absolute xpath. Anyways, any thoughts anyone? It's just a list of x items and I just want to select one...It seems very simple, I feel like I'm missing something. -- Anyways, thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

How would you, as a human, decide which element from the dropdown to choose?

If it's the first entry you can use [`WebList.Select`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib%7EWebList.html#Select) with an index e.g. `"#0"` for the first element.

If it's some data that appears elsewhere in the page you can extract that value (perhaps with `GetROProperty`) and then use that in `Select`.